# Jetty as a library: how to handle multiple threads?

Tags: java, jetty

I am using Jetty 7.0.2 as a library, following the HelloWorld example of http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Jetty_HelloWorld .

My goal is to embed a simple web application in my program. It parses a URI and perform some computationally intensive task. It may take over a minute to complete, returning XML data to the client.

I can do the dispatching myself. But the content generation will be different for each request, and the handle() method of an AbstractHandler implementation will be blocking. So multiple handlers must be ran in separate threads.

How to do this? The QueuedThreadPool does queue threads that connect, but it seems the handle() method is ran only once the previously thread has finished!

Answer (score 0):

If this is the only web app functionality you want to embed, I would suggest you have a look at [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) instead. Like Jetty, it is very easy to embed, but has a highly customizable thread model.